# Creating multiple relationships to existing nodes with Cypher

Tags: neo4j

I am very sorry if this question has been asked before. It seems more basic than it should have been.

I'm trying to evaluate Neo4j for my employer. I had no involvement in setting up the eval environment and it appears to be minimal. I only have the web-based browser & cypher to get anything done. I can't even load a file to the server in order to load by CSV.

And I'm having a lot of trouble loading test data. I chose to use data warehouse metadata as my subject and add :table nodes and then :model nodes (that catalog the diagrams that the tables [APPEAR_ON]). And I should point out ... the APPEAR_ON relationships are sourced from a many-to-many relationship in the RDMS: A model holds many tables; a table can appear on multiple models. So I don't think I'm able to load the relationships at the same time as the nodes. I don't know what else to try other than to load all nodes and then all relationships. COMMENT?

- I can load :table nodes and :model nodes just fine by pulling
  together the many CREATE/MERGE statements on separate lines and
  pasting them into the cypher query tool in the browser.
- I also created indexes / uniqueness constraints for these labels after I created the nodes. (I loaded ID properties for each.)
- BUT I CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO CREATE THE RELATIONSHIPS using the multiple-statements approach.

  `MATCH (t:table),(m:model) WHERE t.tid = "T0525" AND m.mid = "M001" CREATE (t)-[R00864:APPEARS_IN]->(m)
  MATCH (t:table),(m:model) WHERE t.tid = "T0526" AND m.mid = "M001" CREATE (t)-[R00865:APPEARS_IN]->(m)`

Unfortunately, I can only make this work one at a time by including RETURN at the end of the statement. When I send multiple statements, I get an error that says I need to include a WITH statement between the CREATE of the first statement and the MATCH of the second statement.

Many thanks for your ideas!

Answer (score 12):

For formatting queries, check the top right box of the [cypher refcard](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.0/cypher-refcard/).  Your queries are mostly right, but you're trying to do too much I think.  You can't do multiple match/create blocks like that, without a `with`.

So one way to rewrite this is to do it as two queries:

```
MATCH (t:table),(m:model) WHERE t.tid = "T0525" AND m.mid = "M001" CREATE (t)-[R00864:APPEARS_IN]->(m);

MATCH (t:table),(m:model) WHERE t.tid = "T0526" AND m.mid = "M001" CREATE (t)-[R00865:APPEARS_IN]->(m);
```

But you're "re-matching" that same model twice.  So you could also do this:

```
MATCH  (t1:table { tid: "T0525" }), 
       (m:model {mid: "M001"}), 
       (t2:table { tid: "T0526 })
CREATE (t1)-[R00864:APPEARS_IN]->(m),
       (t2)-[R00865:APPEARS_IN]->(m);
```

Note that I eliminated the `WHERE` by adding the match criteria in as match properties, then I used
a comma to create two separate `CREATE` statements without a separate query, just as you can do the same to do multiple matches.

Comment: That's helpful. I've been able to create relationships for all the tables in a model with a single statement. However, I can't execute multiple statements. I still need to run them one at a time.

Comment: I don't follow - of course you need to execute statements one at a time.  But what is the problem?

Comment: Whoops, I just got your message. I want to load multiple (hundreds... thousands...) statements into the browser and click Execute once. I don't want to execute each statement manually.

Comment: I don't think the browser is very good for that.  You might want to use a batch insert tool, or run those statements through neo4j-shell.  I don't think you're going to find an easy way to do that through the browser interface, that's not really what it's designed for.

Comment: Thank you very much. I see an alternate/advanced UI button on the browser page now. The alternate UI has a tab with the console. I'll take a run at this using that interface. ... Can you recommend any other syntax? For instance, arrays with a ForEach? Not sure if this is a good question.

Comment: @DavidBrown I don't recommend going that route.  You can post a separate question if you like, but I recommend using this: https://github.com/jexp/batch-import  or using the neo4j-shell (you can find a manual via google)